# Validate an email address but no rows are found [There is no row at position 0.' error]

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, validation, email

I am trying to validate an email address where the user inputs their desired email for them to create an account and if the size of the row in the database is more than 0 then the email has been already created if not then the size should be zero.

But my int size won't capture the value of zero and just returns "There is no row at position 0". How would I fix this?

Here is my code

````
        {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE EmailAddress = '" + emailaddress + "' ";
            DataSet mydata = dbConnect.GetDataSet(sql);
            int size = Int32.Parse(mydata.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString());

            if (size > 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your SQL to be:

```
String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM Users WHERE EmailAddress = '" + emailaddress + "' ";
```

This way, it will return you an integer, you just check whether the returned integer is greater than 0 or not.

Your original SQL returns an empty result when there is no match found, which is why you saw that error.

To use count(*) in the SQL avoids that situation.